# Getting NoReverseMatch error in Django when accessing the urls using slug

Tags: python, django

> I am newbie on python Django. when following [Django Tutorial](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/microblog-kitchen-sink/#toc13), I
>   have trouble with url for slug field. I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.7.6.

## Error Details

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments
'{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'blog/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

Getting the above error when I try to access the url using `slug`. But when I tried with `pk` it worked fine, no error was encountered.

## Source Code

#### miniblog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^blog/", include("blog.urls", namespace="blog",app_name="blog")),)
```

#### blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$",views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    )
```

#### blog/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)#save the timestamp when the model first creatred and not the field is editable in admin
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,blank=True,default='') #blank = True i.e it is not required for validatipn purpose , default = '' for not slug provided
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at", "title"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, ** kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) #title become the slug
        super(Post, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

#### blog/views.py

```
class PublishedPostMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PublishedPostMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(published=True)

class PostDetailView(PublishedPostMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
```

#### post_list.html

```
{% extends "_layouts/base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}
{% block page_title %}Blog posts | {%endblock%}
{% block page_content%}
<h2>Blog Posts</h2>
<ul>
    {% for post in post_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.slug %}"> {{ post.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>
        Sorry, no posts yet. Check back soon!
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{%endblock%}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `post.slug` seems to be empty. Try printing it in your template to confirm.

Comment: when I print the slugs it came out as non empty.

Comment: It will give you this error even if one of them is empty. Please double check!

Comment: Thanks Selcuk. You seemed to have solved my nightmare :) . How did you know that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that one of your `post.slug`s is empty:

```
...with arguments '(u'',)' ...
```

Double check them by printing in your template or using your database client.